# Can I leave an unused open-drain output disconnected?

Tags: open-drain, floating-pin

I'm designing a circuit using the [MAX22203](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX22203-2327372.pdf) motor driver and it has a few open drain outputs to indicate current throttling. In my design I don't need to read these outputs, so my question is what should I do with them? Should I connect to ground, leave floating or use a pull-up resistor as indicated on the datasheet (page 16)?

I'm inclined to leave the pins disconnected, but what's giving me pause is the wording in the datasheet that says:

> A pullup resistor must be connected from the CDR_ pins to the controller voltage supply.

Do they mean that in order for me to read the data I need a pullup, or does it mean the chip will not drive my motors without a pull-up connected here? (I think the later case is unlikely, but that's why I'm asking.)

Comment: Basically, *read the datasheet*. (No, I'm not going to read that one for you.) Sometimes, and for some open-drain outputs, they will actually specify a needed pull-up even if the output isn't in use. In those cases, follow their recommendations. Otherwise? Probably fine.

Comment: The normal meaning of "must" is highly recommended, and implicitly we make no guarantees what the chip will do if this recommendation is not followed.It is only very slightly weaker than "shall" in a formal document.

Comment: @jonk I did read the datasheet, hence the quoted sentence. But I'm still learning and didn't know how to properly interpret it...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they are needed. Normally unused open drain outputs can be left alone. When they say "to the controller voltage supply" I believe they mean to the supply voltage for the external controller that is monitoring the outputs. This is more clear if you read the whole section for context. Emphasis added.

> The CDR_ pins are active-low open-drain outputs, which are asserted
> during the fixed tOFF decay interval enforced by the integrated
> current drive regulation loop. An ***external controller*** monitoring the
> CDR_ pins can determine whether the integrated current drive
> regulation loop has taken control of the driver overwriting the status
> of the PWM logic inputs (DIN1, DIN2).
>
> The CDR_ signals can be used by an ***external controller*** for a variety
> of reasons and provides information about the actual load during
> current regulation. For example, in the use case where the PWM are
> permanently held in Forward or Reverse mode, control of the motor
> current is entrusted to the internal Current Drive Regulation loop and
> the CDR_ pin status directly reflects the driver output status. In
> this example, the duty cycle of the CDR_ pin can be used to detect
> stall conditions.
>
> A pullup resistor must be connected from the CDR_ pins to the
> ***controller voltage supply***. The pullup resistor choice depends on the
> PCB line capacitance, PWM frequency, and power consumption. Values
> between 1KΩ to 5KΩ satisfy the requirement for most applications.

If you don't connect the signals to a controller, then what controller voltage would you even pull them up to? So I doubt the pullups are needed. But, obviously, the safest thing to do is put the pullups in the schematic and layout. You can leave them out during assembly. But if you later find you need to put them in, then it is just a minor rework to do so. Unless the board layout is so tight that you can't fit two little resistors in there.

Comment: Thanks, I can still pull them to the current regulator voltage that powers the controller and other IO. My board layout is pretty tight since I need to fit 12 of these, but I'll play it safe and try to add the resistors on the layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely leave them open circuit. A pullup is only necessary if you want to use the signal generated at these pins.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the circuit .. is this near anything sensitive to reflections and EMI? or just a basic power board? open ends means reflections if the frequency is high enough
.. like the other guy I say consult your datasheet .. power rails do not like to be left unloaded and can do strange things

Answer (score 0):

I have seen chips where the open drain output was dual purpose - being monitored by the chip itself. That allows implication of "wired or" logic and may allow open drain outputs of two or more chips beIN paralleled. If the datasheet doesn't elaborate on such option it is probably safe to leave the pin open.